# Editing php.ini to allow certain features

Tags: json, php

Okay, so I've been testing and building a website on my computer through localhost. Everything works fine on my computer! I wanted to then upload it to my godaddy hosting account. Then I get an error. I am using json_decode as an argument for one of for each loops in my php. When I'm running my site through a hosting provider it tells me there is an invalid argument in the foreach() loop on like 43. So, I knew it had to do with my php.ini file, so I copied the one from my computer and pasted it in the php.ini file on godaddy, for my site. Then the foreach() loop worked! But, then all kinds of hell broke loose. Session problems and such. So, my question is, what do I need to add to make json_decode work?

Thanks

Here is my php.ini file with the hosting provider:

```
register_globals = off
allow_url_fopen = off

expose_php = Off
max_input_time = 60
variables_order = "EGPCS"
extension_dir = ./
extension=json.so
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
precision = 12
SMTP = relay-hosting.secureserver.net
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="


; Only uncomment zend optimizer lines if your application requires Zend Optimizer    
support

;[Zend]
;zend_optimizer.optimization_level=15
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.3
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer_TS-3.3.3
;zend_extension=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.3/ZendExtensionManager.so
;zend_extension_ts=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer_TS-3.3.3/ZendExtensionManager_TS.so


; -- Be very careful to not to disable a function which might be needed!
; -- Uncomment the following lines to increase the security of your PHP site.

;disable_functions = "highlight_file,ini_alter,ini_restore,openlog,passthru,
;                 phpinfo, exec, system, dl, fsockopen, set_time_limit,
;
```

Comment: go daddy is a terrible host with lots of limits, so im not at all surprised this would not be supported. Yo need to talk to them to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You cant just replace the php.ini file because it has paths hard coded.

For example, with your session error, most likely the setting session.save_path is referencing a directory that doesn't exist or incorrect permissions.

Can you post the line of code that was on line 43? I am guessing that your local php.ini doesn't display the error whereas the godaddy config does.

Comment: All it says " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: Yes, and it says that error is for line 43. What is on line 43? should be foreach(...